# How to async task and Mailchimp API v3.0

Tags: c#, automation, console-application, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to get from MailChimp a MailChimp List Collection.  I have set up the process as displayed in the example on MailChimp.net for getting all lists but it exits out before the list is returned unless I use a Console read after the task is called.  How do I get this supposedly simple task to work?

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{

    AddUpdateMailChimp();

    Console.Read();

}

static async void AddUpdateMailChimp()

{

    lstIDs = await Get_MailChimp_Info();

    for(int i = 0; i < lstIDs.Count; i++)

    {

        AddUpDateMailChimpAsync(lstIDs[i]);
    }

}

private static async Task< List< string >> Get_MailChimp_Info()

{

    var lstIDs  = new List< string > ();

    apikey = GetApiKey() //from config file

    manager = new MailChimpManager(apikey);
    //............below line is where it bombs unless I use a concole.Read in the main..........//

   **IEnumerable< MailChimp.Net.Models.List> mailChimpListCollection = await manager.Lists.GetAllAsyunc().ConfigureAwait( continueOnCapturedContext: false);**

    ............catch statements

    //.......foreach loop to get the list Ids
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem recently. Because `AddUpdateMailChimp()` is async, then the `Main()` method is continuing execution as soon as it hits it, and not waiting on the result.

Also the method returns void so it's seen as fire-and-forget.

If you want to be able to await it, then it should return a task.

That way, in `Main()` you can do

`var result = AddUpdateMailChimp().Result;`

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go.